# Problema ao gerar conteúdo via Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um problema que dependendo do texto selecionado na primeira caixa de seleção ele não carrega os anos relativos a ele no banco de dados. Somente quando o texto carregado na primeira caixa não possui espaço o jquery funciona.

*Segue o arquivo com as caixas de seleção "gera_html.php"*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gerador Planos de Ensino</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./css/styles.css" > 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/ver_selects.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#departamentos').change(function(){
            $('#anos').load('anos.php?departamentos='+$('#departamentos').val() );

        });
    });
</script>   
</head>
<?php

  include "valida_cookies.inc";
  require("connect.php");

?>
<body>
<form class="cad_admin" method="GET" action="anos.php" autocomplete="on" >
<ul>
<h2>Gerador Planos de Ensino</h2>
<li>
<li><label>Escolha um Departamento</label>
<select name="departamentos"  id="departamentos" >
<?php
require("connect.php");
$depto_result=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT DepartamentoDoResponsavel FROM  responsavel ORDER BY    DepartamentoDoResponsavel ASC");
echo "<option value='00'>".'Escolha um departamento'."</option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($depto_result)){
echo "<option>".$row['DepartamentoDoResponsavel']."</option>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
</select></li>      

</select></li>      
<li><label>Ano</label>
<select name="anos" id="anos">
    <option value="00">Escolha um Ano</option>
</select></li>
<li>
 <button class="submit" type="submit">Gerar</button>
</li>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*E aqui o anos.php sendo chamado no jquery*

```
$departamento = $_GET['departamentos'];
echo $departamento;
require('connect.php');

     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT AnoDeAplicacao FROM planodeensino 
    WHERE planodeensino.DepartamentoPorExtenso = '$departamento'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<option value='0'>".'Escolha um Ano'."</option>";

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    echo "<option>".$linha['AnoDeAplicacao']."</option>";
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Se fizer `echo  $sql;` no `anos.php` o que lhe dá?

Comment: Já tentou dar um `trim()` no seu `$('#departamentos').val()`?

Comment: Por favor, arrume esse código, se não: `?departamentos=';DROP+TABLE+planodeensino;--`

Comment: Concordo, faça algum tratamento no código ou utilize PDO para evitar problemas com SQL injection.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues: com certeza o código é muito vulnerável e isto precisa ser tratado, mas teu exemplo específico é inofensivo porque o comando mysql_query da (obsoleta) extensão mysql do PHP só roda uma query por vez (o que vem após o ponto e vírgula é ignorado)

Comment: A variável $sql está assim SELECT DISTINCT AnoDeAplicacao FROM planodeensino 
  WHERE planodeensino.DepartamentoPorExtenso = 'MECÂNICA' caso tenha usado o echo

Comment: Estou tentando resolver isso antes de trocar para PDO, obrigado pela preocupação.

Comment: Eu não sabia disso: já faz um bom tempo que não uso essa extensão. De qualquer modo é melhor evitar.

Comment: Seu código pode até ignorar algo após o ponto-virgula, mas ele não vai ignorar algo como`' OR 1=1 \`. Se isso vai exibir toda sua tabela em uma página ou se vai permitir que a pessoa logue com senha errada, ainda é um problema. Coisas ruins ainda podem acontecer mesmo se usar `DROP TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o método `param` do jQuery vai te ajudar: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Experimente mudar a linha que chama o `load` do jQuery deixando ela assim:

```
$('#anos').load('anos.php?' + $.param({ departamentos: $('#departamentos').val() }) );
```

---

Outra coisa: sua aplicação está usando ISO-8859-1, só que Ajax é UTF-8. Para resolver isso, mude a primeira linha do script "anos.php" para:

```
$departamento = utf8_decode($_GET['departamentos']);
```

Comment: Ele carrega os com espaço e sem espaço mas só quando eles não possuem acentuação.

Comment: Acrescentei novas orientações na resposta acima. Se funcionar, lembre-se de aceitar a minha resposta como correta clicando no "V" ao lado. ;-) Você também pode clicar na setinha para cima para me dar um "voto" a favor... obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, quanto a setinha clicada não foi possível por falta de reputação da minha parte, desculpe por isso.

Comment: @user4725 - Beleza, sem problemas. Valeu! Fico feliz que a resposta tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua query tente utilizar `LIKE %%`ao envés de comparação, pelo que entendi, creio que resolva:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT AnoDeAplicacao FROM planodeensino WHERE planodeensino.DepartamentoPorExtenso LIKE %$departamento%"
```

Comment: Olá mesmo com o LIKE ainda não carrega os espaçados tinha esquecido de avisar que já realizei a troca.

Comment: Já tentou codificar antes de requisitar?:
`encodeURIComponent($('#departamentos').val())`

Comment: Se faço isso o carregamento da segunda caixa não funciona, obrigado pela rapidez nas respostas.